# extracting data from a text file

Tags: extract

I am trying to extract a data (temperature) from a text file downloaded from `wget`.

eg. `wget http://www.weatherzone.com.au/sa/adelaide/adelaide`

How to I extract the information which is "18.6" from the file and copy it to another file to be used by another application?

```
less adelaide
---snip---
'<span id="top_obs_temp" class="tempnow">18.6&deg;C</span>'
---snip---
```

TIA

Comment: This is the actual text in the file not the 18.6 degrees


"<span id="top_obs_temp" class="tempnow">18.6&deg;C</span>"

Answer (score 0):

Use `awk`

```
$ wget http://www.weatherzone.com.au/sa/adelaide/adelaide
$ awk  -F '[<|>|&]' '/tempnow/ {print $3}' adelaide
20.0
```

or all-in-one

```
$ wget -q -O- http://www.weatherzone.com.au/sa/adelaide/adelaide | awk  -F '[<|>|&]' '/tempnow/ {print $3}' 
20.1
```

This works as long as the attribute `class` with the value `tempnow` is available in the `span` tag.

```
<span id="top_obs_temp" class="tempnow">18.6&deg;C</span>
```

---

And now I'm blacklisted **o_O** **:P**

```
wget http://www.weatherzone.com.au/sa/adelaide/adelaide                                                  
--2015-11-06 08:17:37--  http://www.weatherzone.com.au/sa/adelaide/adelaide
Resolving www.weatherzone.com.au (www.weatherzone.com.au)... 104.101.241.181
Connecting to www.weatherzone.com.au (www.weatherzone.com.au)|104.101.241.181|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2015-11-06 08:17:37 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

Comment: using `awk` +1 =)

Comment: TTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2015-11-06 08:17:37 ERROR 403: Forbidden.

--- is that what it is? I also get the same thing now :(
--- I can't test awk now since I am getting blocked as well

Comment: I will check it today again. I could start the script 5 times?